# WebGL bugged code won't render a square

Tags: javascript, webgl

i had a three month rest from game development and I have to remember all the things now... i have started from scratch and am trying to render a white square on a black background. There seems to be a bug that i can't seem to find for hours, so i ask you for help guys. I would be really happy if someone could check my code.

Code link: http://gamedevelopment.free.bg/javascript/webgl-init.js
Page link: http://gamedevelopment.free.bg/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I did not know about Code Review Stack Exchange... I will post there for code reviews from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you're trying to render a triangle in your code, not a square.
You seem to have renamed your variables storing the uniform locations,
thus in your `setMatrixUniforms` function the uniforms are not set to the proper locations.

```
shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
//...
function setMatrixUniforms(){
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrix, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrix, false, mvMatrix);
}
```